# The type System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console-application

Getting an `error` in console app as:

> The type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

But don't know how to add reference for this assembly in app.config?

I tried to add as:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.Entity" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

But that is not working. How to solve this?

Comment: That's a binding redirect, not a reference.

Comment: @CodeCaster, So how can I get rid of that error?

Comment: By adding a reference, which is thoroughly documented on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the reference through the `Add reference` dialog. You can get there by right-clicking the references in the solution explorer:

BTW: usually `System.Data.Entity` is needed for a `nuget` package. `EntityFramework` for example. If it is, you should add the nuget package instead.

[image]

And add the reference:

[image]

Comment: That solved problem, I have just added reference for EntityFramework and not to 'Sytem.Data.Entity'.